# Force jQuery.ajax error result from ASP.NET MVC 3 Action

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

On the client, I am doing a standard ajax call to an MVC action.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/FileUpload/CheckGuess/',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: jsonSerialized,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                dfd.resolve();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                dfd.reject();
            }
        });
```

My `CheckGuess` action returns a `JsonResult`. I want to notify an ajax call that there was an error to invoke `error:` handler. How do I do it with HTTP response (I've read it's better then sending obligatory json and parsing it in a `success:` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should return an error status code from the action. 
For example a status 500, means an internal error in the application. You could also use some of the 400 errors as well.
The error callback should be called for any other status outside the 200 range.

The status code in the application is set to the response object.

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: In MVC3 to return a 500 you could use `return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);`. Not sure what error is preferable in this situation (if it matters), but you could use `return new HttpNotFoundResult();` as well. Each of these also have an overload with a statusDescription parameter if you'd like to use it as well.